# Sphinx Verbatim (Code block) inside mdframed environment

Tags: verbatim, mdframed, sphinx

My code-block don`t break on new page when a use code-block inside mdframed environmen:

```
\begin{mdframed}

\begin{sphinxVerbatim}[commandchars=\\\{\}]
Tablespaces:
PRIMARY (1)
    Full path: /home/test/employee.fdb
    Tables:
        COUNTRY
        JOB
    Indices:
        RDB\PYGZdl{}PRIMARY1 (COUNTRY)
        RDB\PYGZdl{}FOREIGN23 (CUSTOMER)
        RDB\PYGZdl{}PRIMARY22 (CUSTOMER)
TS1 (2)
    Full path: /home/test/ts.ts
    Tables:
        EMPLOYEE
        PROJECT
        SALES
    Indices:
        CUSTNAMEX (CUSTOMER)
        MAXSALX (JOB)
        NEEDX (SALES)
        QTYX (SALES)
TS2 (3)
    Full path: /home/test/ts2.ts
    Tables:
        CUSTOMER
    Indices:
        CUSTREGION (CUSTOMER)
TS3 (4)
    Full path: /home/test/ts3.ts
    Tablespace is empty
\end{sphinxVerbatim}

\end{mdframed}
```

Settings:

```
 \mdfsetup{%
        middlelinewidth=0.5pt,
        backgroundcolor=white!98!black, 
        roundcorner=5pt,
        innerleftmargin = 10pt,
        innertopmargin=2pt,
        innerbottommargin=2pt,
        skipabove = 10pt,
        skipbelow = 5pt,
        shadow=true,
        shadowsize=4pt,
        nobreak=false,
        rightmargin=0pt,
    }
```

My result:
[image]

If I do only \begin{sphinxVerbatim}[commandchars=\{}] ... \end{sphinxVerbatim} (without mdframed) pagebreaks works.

Environment sphinxVerbatim is:

```
\newenvironment{sphinxVerbatim}{%
  % first, let's check if there is a caption
  \ifx\sphinxVerbatimTitle\empty
      \sphinxvspacefixafterfrenchlists
      \parskip\z@skip
      \vskip\sphinxverbatimsmallskipamount
      % there was no caption. Check if nevertheless a label was set.
      \ifx\sphinxLiteralBlockLabel\empty\else
      % we require some space to be sure hyperlink target from \phantomsection
      % will not be separated from upcoming verbatim by a page break
          \needspace{\sphinxliteralblockwithoutcaptionneedspace}%
          \phantomsection\sphinxLiteralBlockLabel
      \fi
  \else
     \parskip\z@skip
     \if t\spx@opt@literalblockcappos
       \vskip\spx@abovecaptionskip
       \def\sphinxVerbatim@Before
           {\sphinxVerbatim@Title\nointerlineskip
            \kern\dimexpr-\dp\strutbox+\sphinxbelowcaptionspace
                 % if no frame (code-blocks inside table cells), remove
                 % the top padding (better visually)
                 \ifspx@opt@verbatimwithframe\else
                    % but we must now check if there is a background color
                    % MEMO: "fcolorbox@setup" will have been done by time of use
                    \ifspx@boxes@withbackgroundcolor\else-\spx@boxes@padding@top\fi
                \fi
                 % caption package adds \abovecaptionskip vspace, remove it
                 \spx@ifcaptionpackage{-\abovecaptionskip}{}\relax}%
     \else
       \vskip\sphinxverbatimsmallskipamount
       \def\sphinxVerbatim@After
          {\nointerlineskip\kern\dimexpr\dp\strutbox
            \ifspx@opt@verbatimwithframe\else
                    % but we must now check if there is a background color
                    % MEMO: "fcolorbox@setup" will have been done by time of use
                    \ifspx@boxes@withbackgroundcolor\else-\spx@boxes@padding@bottom\fi
            \fi
            \spx@ifcaptionpackage{-\abovecaptionskip}{}\relax
           \sphinxVerbatim@Title}%
     \fi
     \def\@captype{literalblock}%
     \capstart
     % \sphinxVerbatimTitle must reset color
     \setbox\sphinxVerbatim@TitleBox
            \hbox{\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}%
     % caption package may detect wrongly if top or bottom, so we help it
                    \spx@ifcaptionpackage
                      {\caption@setposition{\spx@opt@literalblockcappos}}{}%
                    \sphinxVerbatimTitle
                  \end{minipage}}%
  \fi
  \global\let\sphinxLiteralBlockLabel\empty
  \global\let\sphinxVerbatimTitle\empty
  % the "FrameCommand"'s are also responsible to attach the "Title".
  \let\FrameCommand     \sphinxVerbatim@FrameCommand
  % those will also check status of the pre_box-decoration-break option
  \let\FirstFrameCommand\sphinxVerbatim@FirstFrameCommand
  \let\MidFrameCommand  \sphinxVerbatim@MidFrameCommand
  \let\LastFrameCommand \sphinxVerbatim@LastFrameCommand
  %
  \ifspx@opt@verbatimhintsturnover\else
      \let\sphinxVerbatim@Continued\@empty
      \let\sphinxVerbatim@Continues\@empty
  \fi
  % initialization for \spx@boxes@fcolorbox from sphinxpackageboxes.sty
  % it will take into account status of verbatimwithframe Boolean
  \spx@verb@boxes@fcolorbox@setup
  \ifspx@opt@verbatimwrapslines
    % deep hack into fancyvrb's internal processing of input lines
    \let\FV@@PreProcessLine\spx@verb@@PreProcessLine
    % space character will allow line breaks
    \let\FV@Space\spx@verbatim@space
    % allow breaks at special characters using \PYG... macros.
    \sphinxbreaksatspecials
    % breaks at punctuation characters . , ; ? ! and / (needs catcode activation)
    \fvset{codes*=\sphinxbreaksviaactive}%
  \fi
  \let\FancyVerbFormatLine\sphinxFancyVerbFormatLine
  \VerbatimEnvironment
  % workaround to fancyvrb's check of current list depth
  \def\@toodeep {\advance\@listdepth\@ne}%
  % The list environment is needed to control perfectly the vertical space.
  % Note: \OuterFrameSep used by framed.sty is later set to \topsep hence 0pt.
  % - if caption: distance from last text baseline to caption baseline is
  %   A+(B-F)+\ht\strutbox, A = \abovecaptionskip (default 10pt), B =
  %   \baselineskip, F is the framed.sty \FrameHeightAdjust macro, default 6pt.
  %   Formula valid for F < 10pt.
  % - distance of baseline of caption to top of frame is like for tables:
  %   \sphinxbelowcaptionspace (=0.5\baselineskip)
  % - if no caption: distance of last text baseline to code frame is S+(B-F),
  %   with S = \sphinxverbatimtopskip (=\smallskip)
  % - and distance from bottom of frame to next text baseline is
  %   \baselineskip+\parskip.
  % The \trivlist is used to avoid possible "too deeply nested" error.
  \itemsep   \z@skip
  \topsep    \z@skip
  \partopsep \z@skip
  % trivlist will set \parsep to \parskip (which itself is set to zero above)
  % \leftmargin will be set to zero by trivlist
  \rightmargin\z@
  \parindent  \z@% becomes \itemindent. Default zero, but perhaps overwritten.
  \trivlist\item\relax
     \ifspx@inframed\setbox\sphinxVerbatim@ContentsBox\vbox\bgroup
        \@setminipage\hsize\linewidth
        % use bulk of minipage paragraph shape restores (this is needed
        % in indented contexts, at least for some)
        \textwidth\hsize \columnwidth\hsize \@totalleftmargin\z@
        \leftskip\z@skip \rightskip\z@skip  \@rightskip\z@skip
     \else
       \ifsphinxverbatimwithminipage\noindent\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}\fi
       \MakeFramed {% adapted over from framed.sty's snugshade environment
        \advance\hsize-\width\@totalleftmargin\z@\linewidth\hsize\@setminipage
        }%
     \fi
     % For grid placement from \strut's in \FancyVerbFormatLine
     \lineskip\z@skip
     % active comma should not be overwritten by \@noligs
     \ifspx@opt@verbatimwrapslines
       \let\verbatim@nolig@list \sphinx@verbatim@nolig@list
     \fi
     % optimization: as codelines will be handled inside boxes, \everypar is
     % never reset, and it issues \@minipagefalse repeatedly (from \@setminipage).
     % As fancyvrb Verbatim will do \@minipagefalse itself, let's simplify things.
     \everypar{}%
     \color@begingroup % protect against color leaks (upstream framed.sty bug)
     \ifspx@pre@withtextcolor\color{VerbatimTextColor}\fi % mostly shadowed by
                                % Pygments highlighting anyhow
     \spx@pre@TeXextras
     % will fetch its optional arguments if any
     \OriginalVerbatim
}%
{%
  \endOriginalVerbatim
  \color@endgroup % matches the \color@begingroup
  \ifspx@inframed
   \egroup % finish \sphinxVerbatim@ContentsBox vbox
   \nobreak % update page totals
%%%%
% MEMO (2022/07/09, while preparing 5.1.0 LaTeX CSS-style sphinxsetup options)
% This test will systematically cause to abandon framing if the code-block
% is near bottom of a warning-type notice which TeX has not yet decided whether
% it fits on current page and which is near bottom of page.  Indeed the
% \pagetotal will already be very near \pagegoal. This is probably a not
% intended behaviour, and perhaps the whole thing should be removed?  Indeed
% the result is surprising then because the notice will be split, code-block
% will be on page 2 and will have no background-color, no border.
   \ifdim\dimexpr
         \ht\sphinxVerbatim@ContentsBox+
         \dp\sphinxVerbatim@ContentsBox+
         \ht\sphinxVerbatim@TitleBox+
         \dp\sphinxVerbatim@TitleBox+
         % 6.2.0 uses here the dimen registers from sphinxpackageboxes.sty,
         % they got setup by \spx@verb@boxes@fcolorbox@setup
         \spx@boxes@padding@top+
         \spx@boxes@padding@bottom+
         \ifspx@opt@verbatimwithframe \spx@boxes@border@top+
                                      \spx@boxes@border@bottom+\fi
         % try to account for external frame parameters
         % MEMO: this is because the sphinxheavybox (for warning admonitions)
         %       environment sets \FrameSep and \FrameRule
         % TODO: fix this bad implicit dependency
         \FrameSep+\FrameRule+
         % Usage here of 2 baseline distances is empirical.
         % In border case where code-block fits barely in remaining space,
         % it gets framed and looks good but the outer frame may continue
         % on top of next page and give (if no contents after code-block)
         % an empty framed line, as testing showed.
         2\baselineskip+
         % now add all to accumulated page totals and compare to \pagegoal
         \pagetotal+\pagedepth>\pagegoal
    % long contents: do not \MakeFramed. Do make a caption (either before or
    % after) if title exists. Continuation hints across pagebreaks dropped.
    % FIXME? a bottom caption may end up isolated at top of next page
    %        (no problem with a top caption, which is default)
    \spx@opt@verbatimwithframefalse
    \def\sphinxVerbatim@Title{\noindent\box\sphinxVerbatim@TitleBox\par}%
    \sphinxVerbatim@Before
    \noindent\unvbox\sphinxVerbatim@ContentsBox\par
    \sphinxVerbatim@After
   \else
    % short enough contents: use \MakeFramed. As it is nested, this requires
    % minipage encapsulation.
    \noindent\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}%
     \MakeFramed {% Use it now with the fetched contents
      \advance\hsize-\width\@totalleftmargin\z@\linewidth\hsize\@setminipage
      }%
     \unvbox\sphinxVerbatim@ContentsBox
     % the \@minipagefalse is superfluous, actually.
     \par\unskip\@minipagefalse\endMakeFramed
    \end{minipage}%
   \fi
  \else % non-nested \MakeFramed
    \par\unskip\@minipagefalse\endMakeFramed % from framed.sty snugshade
    \ifsphinxverbatimwithminipage\end{minipage}\fi
  \fi
  \endtrivlist
}
```

What can I do that code breaks?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!